# WooCommerce how to show product list in datewise? Rightnow it is showing as Alphabetical

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website. In the shop or product categories page the products are listed in alphabetical order, I want to order them date wise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you please edit this question to include your code and other details?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet that will be handy for many of you! This snippet allows you to create a new default sorting method to list your products from oldest to most recent. To use it, simply add the following code in the file called functions.php in your theme folder:

```
<?php
// Filters
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

 // Apply custom args to main query
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'oldest_to_recent' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'date';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    }

    return $args;
}

// Create new sorting method
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {

    $sortby['oldest_to_recent'] = __( 'Oldest to most recent', 'woocommerce' );

    return $sortby;
}
```